# Do adamantium or vibranium smell; and if so, what do they smell like?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, vibranium

So I just watched *Logan*, and I noticed that Caliban smelled the vibranium bullet. In *Black Panther*, Klaw similarly smells the vibranium relic in the museum.

I know these are two different movie continuities, but in general (comics, movies, wherever), do adamantium and/or vibranium have a unique odor? If so, what does it/do they smell like?

Comment: It sounds like you have answered your own question.

Comment: It smells exactly like iocane powder.

Comment: *Logan* and *Black Panther* are from two different film continuities, and the metal in *Logan* is adamantium, not vibranium.

Comment: Adamantium is a Steel and Vibranium alloy.

Comment: This question seems to mix two seperate continuities.

Comment: It does, I was wondering in the comics was there ever a time where a character says, "Hey, Vibranium kinda smells like x."

Comment: [Smells like victory!](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-love-the-smell-of-napalm-in-the-morning)

Comment: @MnIce: “Adamantium is a Steel and Vibranium alloy” — not in *Logan* it’s not. (Note that the 2017 Wolverine movie is called *Logan*; [*Old Man Logan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Man_Logan) is the 2008 comic book upon which the movie was very loosely based.)

Comment: It smell like McgGuffinium, with an aftersmell of Unobtainium.

Comment: I think the smell was more for dramatic effect in a character shown to have a flair for the dramatic.

Comment: @Broklynite: definite stage sniff. A sniff with a flourish! I hope we get a flashback showing Klaw’s enthusiastic participation in Johannesburg’s thriving amateur musical theatre community.

Comment: @Broklynite I incorporated your "dramatic effect" into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Smelling Metal

Let's dig out our knowledge about smell first:

Metals don't smell in themselves. They smell because of what sticks to them:

> The compounds people smell are actually aldehydes and ketones, and not any iron-containing compounds.<sup>1</sup>

Our noses are just not made to smell metal ions *in themselves*. But Adamantium is an alloy, right? It is a hellhole of Steel, Vibranium, and Unobtanium<sup>2</sup>. But it still does not emit molecules that actually can be smelled as our nose is a chemical analyzation facility.

So, Klaw can't smell the metal itself because (pure & uncontaminated) metal *does not smell* to the human nose.

## Smelling Vibranium specific organic smear on the surface

Chemistry, biology, and physics established that you can't smell something that doesn't emit some kind of molecule that can be analyzed by our nose. But we do know some things about Adamantium that can help in establishing how it might or might not smell:

- it is rare<sup>3</sup> and an alloy containing Vibranium.
- Depending on the writer, Adamantium is poisonous<sup>3 4 5</sup>

Most alloys share effects with their mother compounds, especially when it comes to toxicity. As Adamantium is poisonous, so should be Vibranium, unless the Unobtanium<sup>2</sup> is.

So, Vibranium is a somewhat poisonous metal, as is lead or arsenic? That indeed can be part of the solution! There are bacteria living in high arsenic surroundings<sup>6</sup> while others ingest lead<sup>7</sup>. The chemical compounds metabolized by these bacteria might or might not contain the actual arsenic or lead, but the presence of these metals in their surroundings do make these chemical compounds very specific. And these compounds are something the olfactoric sense can analyze.

So I propose that Klaw does not smell the actual Vibranium, but the (residue) of some bacteria that is capable of (temporarily) living on it and creating a specific mix of aldehydes and ketones that does not exist anywhere else.

## Klaw the Super Nose

There is one alternative though: That would be that Klaw's nose is not like any humans in a way that he could possibly smell the chemical composition of metals and alloys. Like, he might have a gas chromatograph for a nose. But that still would need metal ions in the air to smell, and we know that Vibranium isn't that kinda metal usually as it is hard to work with. Also, there is no indication in other sources I am aware of, that give Klaw this sort of super-smell.

## Dramatic Effect

Or... Klaw didn't smell the metal at all. He realized what it was from the visuals and did a sniff just for the effects, claiming that he smelled it for the fun of it, as [Broklynite](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/24024/broklynite) pointed out.

<sup>1 - https://phys.org/news/2006-11-metal.html</sup>
<sup>2 - or whatever the current writer wants it to have in it</sup>
<sup>3 - http://time.com/4685052/logan-wolverine-adamantium/</sup> 
<sup>4 - https://www.cbr.com/wolverine-adamantium-poisoning/</sup> 
<sup>5 - https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/656hux/xmen_how_can_adamantium_be_poisoning_wolverine_if/</sup>
<sup>6 - https://www.nature.com/news/arsenic-loving-bacterium-needs-phosphorus-after-all-1.10971</sup>
<sup>7 - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29736824</sup>

Comment: Whilst this is indeed a good answer, it answers from real world perspectives. Do you have any evidence to tie this into the MCU? (Things are probably the same but y'know it's a world with giant purple snappers so there are differences).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot addded alternatives, this answer can't do more than speculate

Comment: Unless this has been directly addressed in the movies or possibly the comics (and I’m betting that it hasn’t) I don’t see there being a much better answer than this.

Comment: @dna: I agree. Edited accordingly!